# Provide additional Data to Server for Pagination via RPC

Tags: gwt, pagination, rpc

I'm working on a GWT project which calls the server via RPC. A typical RPC calls the Server and passes some information and then recieves the answer as an ArrayList.Now we noticed that with a growing database we should use pagination to not overcharge the client with to many objects.

The problem is that there are at the moment many existing  methods which are using RPC and each of them would must be modified to provide the necessary information for pagination (Count of Objects,Current Position ) . If i would change every method i would have to edit the Synchronous Interface,the Asynchronous Interface, and the Server and Client class which are using/implementing them.

I tried to create a generic Wrapper class, but i couldn't make it suitable for out project,because each object must be casted back in the original type. Is there a way with less effort to provide  pagination  without editing many methods?

Comment: How do you expect to implement pagination without editing the server-classes to provide pagination functions, and without editing the client-classes to provide the pagination information?

Comment: Well, something must be edited. I'm searching for a solution with not  that much effort. If nothing better comes to my mind,  i will create a parent class with pagination data and extend it in every class which is used via RPC